# vlcj: libvlc_instance_t not accessible after module creation

Tags: java, eclipse, vlcj, module-info

I have recently migrated my project from Java8 to Java17. I wanted to try out the module system and added a `module-info.java` to my existing Eclipse project. As it caused several issues, I decided to revert back the change and to proceed without declaring modules. I deleted the file, but now I am getting compile errors. It is stated that `LibX11` and `libvlc_instance_t` cannot be resolved to be a type and that they are not accessible. Why is that? It was working fine before. It seems that adding and removing the `module-info.java` has somehow messed up my configuration.
I need to access `libvlc_instance_t` because I need to subclass `MediaPlayer`, which requires a reference to `libvlc_instance_t` in the constructor. If `libvlc_instance_t` is really not meant to be used, how can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Did  you also move things from the Classpath to the Modulepath in build path settings? They will need to be in the Classpath now.

Comment: I see that all my ressources/external libraries are listed below the Modulepath. The Classpath has nothing in it. I am not sure how this looked before tbh., but moving the vlcj libraries to the Classpath solved the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: Btw., I found out that the problem can also be solved by exposing the missing internal vlcj packages in the "Module Dependencies" tab! With this, it is okay for the libraries to remain in the Module Path. It seems this could be an alternate solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: vlcj's adoption of modules is quite recent, it's possible there are issues, posting at the GitHub project page with specific examples might be helpful.